# What is the shorthand in es6 for extracting a property from an Object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to find out if I can do this:

```
    const {todos} = props.todos;
    this.todos = todos;
```

In one line.

Comment: Would you give idea about props variable

Comment: It is a List Immutable. this code is inside the constructor.

Comment: why this.todos = props.todos; doesn't work?

Comment: @ParagBhayani: What the OPs code actually does is `const todos = this.todos = props.todos.todos;`

Answer (score 2):

Yes you could with something like this (if you really like destructuring):

```
let todos = (({ todos } = props.todos), this.todos = todos);
```

*(Note that we need to use `let` instead of `const` since we rebind todos, inside the assignment expression)*

Would I recommend using this, no. This makes the code much more unreadable as compared to you example. It also uses the [comma expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) which is not very well known. There is no harm in using two lines for this code instead of one. The power of the ES6 destructuring is not in reducing the LOC of you JavaScript but to make it easier to understand. Take the default value for instance:

```
let { todos = [] } = props;
```

This is more readable then

```
let todos = props.todos;
todos = todos ? todos : [];
```

Finally this is could work just as well:

```
this.todos = props.todos.todos;
```

Comment: Your first example would be a temporal deadzone error because you're assigning to `todos` via destructuring before `todos` has finished initializing.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are extracting only a single property, you can drop the destructuring and just use

```
const todos = props.todos.todos;
this.todos = todos;
```

> In one line?

```
const todos = this.todos = props.todos.todos;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the assignment but don't need the intermediate `todos` value, you can do:

```
({todos: this.todos} = props.todos);
```

or

```
({todos: {todos: this.todos}} = props);
```

but you really might as well do

```
this.todos = props.todos.todos;
```